# How can I trace the exact location with lat/long and IP address of user using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, geolocation, ip, ip-address

When ever user visited to my site, or open my website site in browser, I want to store all the necessary information of the users like, location , city, county, latitude/longitude and including IP address as well.

Some of the answer I have found and implement them as well. Though they give the location but wasn't the exact location of the User.

Do not suggest me to use freegeoip, dotnetcurry,iplocationtools, etc. all are the useless and does not give exact location.

Comment: You can not get exact lat and long using website because pc are not gps enable. But google API help you to get lat long. its not showing exact but its show nearest location.

Comment: *Do not suggest me to use freegeoip, dotnetcurry,iplocationtools, etc. all are the useless and does not give exact location.*  So you are looking for recommendations, which is **off-topic** Please read the [FAQ] to see what kind of questions that can be asked. Show us what you have tried, enclose a [MCVE] to demonstrate it.

Comment: You can't get the accurate latitude and longitude of user unless the user device has GPS enabled and allow your access the information via browsers. It is unlikely you can solve this through programming. It is a permission problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the google map geolocation, Here I have fetch the latitude, longitude including the exact location of the user where ever they are.
For google map API: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false"

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
}
function success(position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long = position.coords.longitude;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

var geocoder, add, country;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': myLatlng
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
            add = results[1].formatted_address;
            country = results[9].formatted_address;
        } 
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by the exact location? You can never get the EXACT location, if you expect centimeter resolutions!! So, IP addresses provide the location by a limited accuracy. Maybe you'd better to use GPS in GPS-enabled devices to get somewhat more accurate locations.

Comment: with the help of latitude and longitude, may be we can get exact location.

Comment: Latitude and longitude are themselves what define a _location_. I think you are talking about something else. Maybe you want the location in a unit rather than geographical decimal degrees. If I'm right, you should edit your question before I can help you.

Comment: not satisfied with your answer  but anyway i got the exact location of the user whereever they are getting access to my site.